# Hypothesis Testing Coins t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, python

Hey all I'm trying to tackle the following problem:

Suppose we have the results of coin tosses of 3 people:

| Person | Tosses | Heads |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 400 | 58 |
| Y | 100 | 20 |
| Z | 1000 | 120 |

a) Can we claim that the 3 people's tosses are statistically equal?

b) Compare person X and Y. Can we say that they are statistically equal?

c) What is the probability that the heads rate (no of heads/tosses) of person Z is greater than that of person Y?

For b) I thought of using two-sided proportions_ztest but how to compare all 3 samples for a) and what about the probability question? Does cumulative distribution function come to apply?

Thanks

Comment: Part c) is extremely awkward phrasing. Explicitly, it refers to a Bayesian approach. My guess is that your professor means for you to calculate the p-value.

Comment: What do you mean by the ambiguous phrase "statistically equal"?  On the face of it, all three experiments have different results.

Comment: It will be helpful to get the exact phrasing from your homework assignment. If your teacher uses terms like "statistically equal" and "probability that the heads rate", that is different than if you have paraphrased the original wording.